# host multiple pages on nodejs

Tags: node.js

So I have my app at `http://localhost:8080/`

How can I have `http://localhost:8080/subpage` ? Because it seems like any page that hits :8080 pulls the server.js

thanks!

** edit - here's what worked for me (thanks to **stewe's** *answer*) **

```
var app = require('http').createServer(createServer);
var fs = require('fs'); 
var url = require('url');

function createServer(req, res) {
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    var fsCallback = function(error, data) {
        if(error) throw error;

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    }

    switch(path) {
        case '/subpage':
            doc = fs.readFile(__dirname + '/subpage.html', fsCallback);
        break;
        default:
            doc = fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', fsCallback);
        break;
    }
}

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Jackson, in its current form, your question will be closed. You need to provide more details, such as your current code and what you've tried. Also, have you tried Googling your problem? This is a common thing with Node.

Comment: @Brandon, I don't think that's a bad question.  I'm guessing the OP is trying to figure out what Node.js can and cannot do.  I'm not +1-ing it because, yes, he could have googled for it.

Comment: @everyone - I spent nearly an hour "researching" (using google) to find this answer. I didn't find anything that gave this answer away so I moved to my last resort which was SOF. I don't like asking questions here unless I think I'm having a hard time finding the answer. Also, keep in mind I kept this questions simple so that it's an easy read. Why make a complex question for something that most likely has a not-so-complex answer? Perhaps mild ignorance manifests it's self by someone pushing the "close" button..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
var http=require('http');
var url=require('url');

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    var pathname=url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    switch(pathname){
        case '/subpage':
            res.end('subpage');
        break;
        default:
            res.end('default');
        break;
    }

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: ah, that must be where the `rs.readfile(__dirname + '/index.html'` comes in. Marvelous. I'll add this to my question once it's working. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I hit the same problem as you did, and I think what we were both looking for is basically a *routing engine* for node.js. Basically, okay fine I get the hello-world example for nodejs, but how do I build something that responds to different requests?

For future users who land on this page via google, you must look at [Express.js](http://expressjs.com) and this excellent guide and intro into express, [Understanding Express.js](http://evanhahn.com/understanding-express/). These two will solve the problem

Comment: Your link to Understanding Express.js fails. Remove the "-js" on the link or go here: http://evanhahn.com/understanding-express/