# Use socket.io and node.js between webpages

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Is there any way using socket.io to share data between two different webpages?
Let's say I have page1.html and page2.html and they are acessed from different devices in the same network, and from page1 I send a string to page2.
From what I have seen I could make it using node.js and socket.io, based on the chat example from socket.io. However I'm not sure how.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: if you want to synchronize different pages in one site you need to use global scope: window.document. But if you want to synchronize two instances of the same site you can use socket.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a socket server that handles all the web socket connections and events and so on...

The web pages cannot communicate directly but they must send data to the server. One important thing is how you plan to identify the clients.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, send data to server and then, the server send it to the other page. Never tought about how to identify the clients... and I have no ideia how to do it...

Comment: fire the join event  on the cliens ad soon as the web page  is fully loaded and send the "role" of that specific client. When the server recive the id of the client store the ws connection in a array among whit its id. In this way you can program the server to redirect the messages recived to designated clients... However take a look to rooms and namespaces on the socket.io documentation. There might be a better way

Comment: If there are only two pages you don't really need to identify them.. When the message comes from one client you send it to the other... The issue come when you have to handle different multiple pages

Comment: Can I do that with different pages like in this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290836/host-multiple-pages-on-nodejs . Will I be able to display them simultaneously in different browsers?

Comment: Yes you can. I suggest you to use express framework and use routing to serve different pages depending on the URL. If you don't want to use express parse the URL of the request like shown in the the question you posted. To handle multiple web soket connection you need to have them stored somwere: like said before look at rooms and namespaces from soket io or store connections into array